# RLMCollectionChange indexes of modifications bad description?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, realm

According to documentation of `-[RLMCollectionChange modifications]` it returns `The indices in the new version of the collection which were modified.`. But example looks like this:

```
 [tv beginUpdates];
 [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[changes deletionsInSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[changes insertionsInSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 [tv reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[changes modificationsInSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 [tv endUpdates];
```

`UITableView` need indexes in old collection. Is this bad description?

Another question is how to get indexes in new collection?

Debugger show that `RLMCollectionChange` contains `_indices.modifications` and `_indices.modifications_new`. Looks like first one is what `-[RLMCollectionChange modifications]` returns. Second one does not have property to access it ...

Of course you can calculate it. And this how we have to solve this problem at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

A table view needs a new index. Because doing between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` is to make the state of the table view follow the changed model.

Also, neither new nor old is relevant to `modifications`. `modifications` is that the object's position does not change, only the property changes. If a property changes its position to the object, it will be treated as a "move" instead of a modification. Therefore, it is converted to `insertion` and`deletion`, not `modification`.

Comment: So if, for example, before update we have 5 items and we got collectionChange that remove first 4 items and change last one we will have index 0 in modifications? Right now collectionChange say that item with index 4 is modified ...